# Binding an ObservableList to contents of two other ObservableLists?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

If I have two separate ObservableLists, and both are put in a single ObservableList for a TableView... is there a way to create a binding between those two ObservableLists and the aggregated one? I tried to mess around and override the calculate() method for the ObjectBinding, but I don't think this is what I want. Any thoughts on how to tackle this?

UPDATE: Going on a related tangent to show an implication discussed below. This is my ObservableImmutableList implementation that is struggling to work with the checked solution.

```
   package com.nield.utilities.fx;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;

import javafx.beans.InvalidationListener;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;


public final class ObservableImmutableList<T> implements ObservableList<T> {
    private volatile ImmutableList<T> backingList;
    private final CopyOnWriteArrayList<ListChangeListener<? super T>> listeners = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
    private final CopyOnWriteArrayList<InvalidationListener> invalidationListeners = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    private final ObjectProperty<ObservableList<T>> property;

    private ObservableImmutableList(ImmutableList<T> immutableList) {
        this.backingList = immutableList;
        this.property = new SimpleObjectProperty<ObservableList<T>>(this);
    }

    public static <T> ObservableImmutableList<T> of(ImmutableList<T> immutableList) {
        return new ObservableImmutableList<T>(immutableList);
    }

    public void set(ImmutableList<T> immutableList) { 

        this.property.setValue(this);

        final ImmutableList<T> oldList = this.backingList;
        final ImmutableList<T> newList = immutableList;
        listeners.forEach(l -> l.onChanged(new Change<T>(this) {
            private int changeNum = 0;
            @Override
            public boolean next() {
                changeNum++;
                return changeNum <= 2 ? true : false;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean wasUpdated() {
                return true;
            }
            @Override
            public void reset() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
            @Override
            public int getFrom() {
                return 0;
            }
            @Override
            public int getTo() {
                return changeNum == 1 ? oldList.size() - 1 : newList.size() - 1;
            }
            @Override
            public List<T> getRemoved() {
                return changeNum == 1 ? oldList : ImmutableList.of();
            }
            @Override
            public List<T> getAddedSubList() { 
                return changeNum == 1 ? ImmutableList.of() : newList;
            }
            @Override
            protected int[] getPermutation() {
                int[] permutations = new int[changeNum == 1 ? oldList.size() : newList.size()];
                for (int i = 0; i < permutations.length; i++) { 
                    permutations[i] = i;
                }
                return permutations;
            }

        }));
        this.backingList = immutableList;

        invalidationListeners.forEach(l -> l.invalidated(this));

    }

    public ImmutableList<T> get() { 
        return backingList;
    }
    public ObjectProperty<ObservableList<T>> asProperty() { 
        return property;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return backingList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return backingList.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        return backingList.contains(o);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return backingList.iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] toArray() {
        return backingList.toArray();
    }

    @Override
    public <B> B[] toArray(B[] a) {
        return backingList.toArray(a);
    }

    @Override @Deprecated
    public boolean add(T e) {
        return backingList.add(e);
    }

    @Override @Deprecated
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        return backingList.remove(o);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {
        return backingList.containsAll(c);
    }

    @Override @Deprecated
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends T> c) {
        return backingList.addAll(c);
    }

    @Override @Deprecated
    public boolean addAll(int index, Collection<? extends T> c) {
        return backingList.addAll(index, c);
    }

    @Override @Deprecated
    public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
        return backingList.removeAll(c);
    }

    @Override @Deprecated
    public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c) {
        return backingList.retainAll(c);
    }

    @Override @Deprecated
    public void clear() {
        backingList.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public T get(int index) {
        return backingList.get(index);
    }

    @Override @Deprecated
    public T set(int index, T element) {
        return backingList.set(index, element);
    }

    @Override @Deprecated
    public void add(int index, T element) {
        backingList.add(index, element);
    }

    @Override @Deprecated
    public T remove(int index) {
        return backingList.remove(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int indexOf(Object o) {
        return backingList.indexOf(o);
    }

    @Override
    public int lastIndexOf(Object o) {
        return backingList.lastIndexOf(o);
    }

    @Override
    public ListIterator<T> listIterator() {
        return backingList.listIterator();
    }

    @Override
    public ListIterator<T> listIterator(int index) {
        return backingList.listIterator(index);
    }

    @Override
    public ImmutableList<T> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        return backingList.subList(fromIndex, toIndex);
    }

    @Override
    public void addListener(InvalidationListener listener) {
        invalidationListeners.add(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeListener(InvalidationListener listener) {
        invalidationListeners.remove(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void addListener(ListChangeListener<? super T> listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeListener(ListChangeListener<? super T> listener) {
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }

    @Override @Deprecated
    public boolean addAll(T... elements) {
        return backingList.addAll(ImmutableList.copyOf(elements));
    }

    @Override @Deprecated
    public boolean setAll(T... elements) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override @Deprecated
    public boolean setAll(Collection<? extends T> col) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override @Deprecated
    public boolean removeAll(T... elements) {
        return backingList.removeAll(ImmutableList.copyOf(elements));
    }

    @Override @Deprecated
    public boolean retainAll(T... elements) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override @Deprecated
    public void remove(int from, int to) {
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() { 
        return backingList.toString();
    }

}
```

And here is the static factory to merge two ObservableLists together so far. It works for standard implementations of ObservableList, but it is not working with my ObservableImmutableList implementation.

```
package com.nield.finance;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;
import com.nield.utilities.fx.ObservableImmutableList;

public class ObservableMerge {
    static ObservableImmutableList<String> a = ObservableImmutableList.of(ImmutableList.of("ABQ","DAL"));
    static ObservableImmutableList<String> b = ObservableImmutableList.of(ImmutableList.of("HOU","PHX"));

    static ObservableList<String> aandb = FXCollections.observableArrayList();


    static ObservableList<String> merge(ObservableList<String> into, ObservableList<String>... lists) {
        final ObservableList<String> list = into;
        for (ObservableList<String> l : lists) {
            list.addAll(l);
            l.addListener((javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change<? extends String> c) -> {
                while (c.next()) {
                    if (c.wasAdded()) {
                        list.addAll(c.getAddedSubList());
                    }
                    if (c.wasRemoved()) {
                        list.removeAll(c.getRemoved());
                    }
                    if (c.wasUpdated()) {
                        list.removeAll(c.getRemoved());
                        list.addAll(c.getAddedSubList());
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        return list;
    }
    public static void main(String...args) {
        merge(aandb, a, b);

        System.out.println(""+aandb);
        a.set(ImmutableList.of("LAX", "BUR"));
        System.out.println(""+aandb);

    }
}

And here is the static factory to merge two ObservableLists (it should work with the ObservableImmutableList too, but its not.


package com.nield.finance;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;
import com.nield.utilities.fx.ObservableImmutableList;

public class ObservableMerge {
    static ObservableImmutableList<String> a = ObservableImmutableList.of(ImmutableList.of("ABQ","DAL"));
    static ObservableImmutableList<String> b = ObservableImmutableList.of(ImmutableList.of("HOU","PHX"));

    static ObservableList<String> aandb = FXCollections.observableArrayList();


    static ObservableList<String> merge(ObservableList<String> into, ObservableList<String>... lists) {
        final ObservableList<String> list = into;
        for (ObservableList<String> l : lists) {
            list.addAll(l);
            l.addListener((javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change<? extends String> c) -> {
                while (c.next()) {
                    if (c.wasAdded()) {
                        list.addAll(c.getAddedSubList());
                    }
                    if (c.wasRemoved()) {
                        list.removeAll(c.getRemoved());
                    }
                    if (c.wasUpdated()) {
                        list.removeAll(c.getRemoved());
                        list.addAll(c.getAddedSubList());
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        return list;
    }
    public static void main(String...args) {
        merge(aandb, a, b);

        System.out.println(""+aandb);
        a.set(ImmutableList.of("LAX", "BUR"));
        System.out.println(""+aandb);

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the algorithm to aggregate both list into the single one? Simple merge/append?

Comment: If you set a new ImmutablList, you call the invalidation listener, that will trigger value recalculations in the value bindings, but not trigger any listChange... How about calling the listChangeListener() also with a remove of all old list values and an add of all new list values?... seems consequent to me....

Comment: Okay so I was on the right track trying to do just that in some capacity. I will take another pass at it and will post the working class...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This might be a starting point:

```
    public class ObservableMerge {
        static ObservableList<String> a = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        static ObservableList<String> b = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        static ObservableList<String> aandb = FXCollections.observableArrayList();


        static ObservableList<String> merge(ObservableList<String> into, ObservableList<String>... lists) {
            final ObservableList<String> list = into;
            for (ObservableList<String> l : lists) {
                list.addAll(l);
                l.addListener((javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change<? extends String> c) -> {
                    while (c.next()) {
                        if (c.wasAdded()) {
                            list.addAll(c.getAddedSubList());
                        }
                        if (c.wasRemoved()) {
                            list.removeAll(c.getRemoved());
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            return list;
        }
        public static void main(String...args) {
            merge(aandb, a, b);

            System.out.println(""+aandb);
            a.add("Hello");
            b.add("Peter");
            System.out.println(""+aandb);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Awesome, this worked really well verbatim. I just made it generic and wrapped it up in a static factory and its good to go!

Comment: A weakness is: it will not work if objects are inserted multiple as the remove() removes all occurenrences... ;-)

Comment: Yeah I kind of figured out there are limitations. For example, I have my own implementation of ObservableList that wraps around an ImmutableList, which can be swapped internally with a new ImmutableList at anytime which invalidates all dependencies. Not sure how to manage the ListChangeListeners for that but it works great for a TableView. But I think for this fringe case with two merged lists containing an ObservableImmutableList I'd use a Guava EventBus instead.

Comment: perhaps the wasUpdated() might be usefull to in the content of your wrapper has changed....

Comment: Okay I'm trying to override the wasUpdated() and giving the abstract Change class what it wants. I'm still not seeing the merged list update. I updated my question above with the WIP for my ObserableImmutableList implementation, and the static factory you provided.

Comment: Okay I corrected the implementation and updated the ObservableImmutableList class above. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Just thought I'd document this for future readers. [RxJavaFX](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJavaFX) makes push-driven tasks like this MUCH easier.

```
    ObservableList<String> list1 = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    ObservableList<String> list2 = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    ObservableList<String> combinedList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    Observable.combineLatest(
                JavaFxObservable.fromObservableList(list1),
                JavaFxObservable.fromObservableList(list2),
            (l1,l2) -> {
                ArrayList<String> combined = new ArrayList<>();
                combined.addAll(l1);
                combined.addAll(l2);
                return combined;
            }).subscribe(combinedList::setAll);

//return unmodifiable version of combinedList
```

Here's a full working example of this at work:

```
    ObservableList<String> list1 = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    ObservableList<String> list2 = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    ObservableList<String> combinedList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    Observable.combineLatest(
                JavaFxObservable.fromObservableList(list1),
                JavaFxObservable.fromObservableList(list2),
            (l1,l2) -> {
                ArrayList<String> combined = new ArrayList<>();
                combined.addAll(l1);
                combined.addAll(l2);
                return combined;
            }).subscribe(combinedList::setAll);

    JavaFxObservable.fromObservableList(combinedList).subscribe(System.out::println);

    list1.add("Alpha");
    list2.add("Beta");
    list1.add("Gamma");
    list1.remove("Alpha");
    list2.add("Delta");

    Thread.sleep(10000);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[]
[Alpha]
[Alpha, Beta]
[Alpha, Gamma, Beta]
[Gamma, Beta]
[Gamma, Beta, Delta]
```

Comment: Is it correct that this solution always returns (or marks as changed) the whole list whereas the other solution above uses JavaFX's "Change" system to inform the listeners of the resulting list only about the changes?

Comment: I think JavaFX does internal validation to see if a "change" is in fact not a change. If this is too brute-force with the `setAll()`, you can always use the other factories in RxJavaFX that are for more fine-tuned change listening: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJavaFX#observablelist-observablemap-and-observableset